# How does the views page style options work?

Tags: views

I have recently discovered the power of Views. I am using the Unformatted list Format and an Entity Reference bringing two content types that I created (myprojects and mytasks) together such that if there are any tasks associated with a given project they are listed below the related project. This works pretty well.

I know very little about HTML and really don't want to have to get into it. I want a simple indentation on each output task row displayed so that the report is easier to read. It would also be nice if it was double spaced.

The theme I'm using in my site is Outreach. What happens is each project is h3 and each row is inside div and underlined with a smaller font.

[image]

This list of projects and tasks becomes an agenda for meetings when copied into Word.

How can I use Settings for Unformatted list and/or Settings for Fields in the view to indent the rows of tasks?

Answer (score 0):

It is a CSS question, not Drupal.

I understand that using the Open Outreach theme you probably run a non-profit organization of some kind, so I'll try to help you.

You already said that you don't want to learn HTML/CSS in other questions so I will try to be straightforward: you can't.

What you might do is change from Unformatted List to HTML List and hope that the basic CSS don't change it. And yes, the preview **will be** different from the final view because templates. The closed admin part uses a template different than the open part.

Comment: I really do appreciate the help. I have a couple of Computer Science degrees, but this business of building a web site with Drupal is challenging! I've spent several hours searching the web for more information about all the choices for format settings such as "Remove tags from rendered output" and "Row class" without any luck. Can you give me pointers on what each of these settings does and how to utilize them?

Comment: To better understand these option you should open a Inspect Element on the page. Get Chrome or Firefox, open one window on the view page as it shows to the end user (let's call it 1) and one window as the admin (2). On 1 open the Inspect tools on the part of the view, on the 2 change any of the attributes and save. Once you refresh 1 you will see the diff. 'Row class' is used to add a class so that you can change it with CSS/JS. As I previously mentioned, you need CSS to style it.

Comment: I am slowly piecing together the pieces of this aspect of Drupal. It is yet another significant learning curve. I followed your above advice and am reading tutorials and watching videos. As I did so I discovered the Sweaver module. Unfortunately, it seems to have bugs. I just discovered Semantic Views and will be studying it and other options. When I come up with a good solution. I'll post what I find here as the answer to my question so that others can benefit.